# What does question mark in PHP represent other than Ternary Operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Is there any other use of the question mark `?` in PHP other than being part as the Ternary Operator.

**Just to take note:** I know about how it works in regex and all that. I am talking about the PHP language itself, not regex or what. I know how it works in opening and closing tags.

I am more concerned about tokenizing a PHP script. Is there any other token involving question mark?

I've already checked the PHP manual by the way.

Comment: It is used in regular expressions too but this is kinda vague question , can u elaborate what u exactly need to know?

Comment: See also the PHP.net manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: @warren - checked, wanted to make sure.

Comment: it's a really weird question.

Comment: Just wanted to check. Anyway this was over quite a long time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well yeah in php it is used for:

- `<?php  / ?>` opening tags.
- `<? ?>`  short opening tags.
- `<?= $variable ?>`  equivalent to  useful when working with templates.
- `?:` ternary operator
- And is used in preg_match() when writing [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.examples.php). `^\s+(\s+)?$`

Comment: not what i'm looking for. please look at the question again. thanks for being specific.

Comment: @Mauris - that's all you're going to find: the question mark is only used there.

Comment: @Mauris If I left an answer that was a solitary 'NO' would you find that helpful? elviejo's response was complete and appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

For one, it is used to mark up the PHP code itself like this `<? ?>` :)

But seriously, are you driving at some particular use you wanted to understand?